# Converting symbols to different symbols in a string

Tags: java, android

Assuming that we have a `String myString = "abcde"`
We need to assign an other symbol for each letter of the entire alphabet, so when a string gets values, they are automatically converted as instructed.
Example: 
"a" becomes "α",
"b" becomes "β",
"c" becomes "σ",
"d" becomes "δ",
"e" becomes "ε"

Where do we even begin?

Comment: create a map which will give you the value corresponding to the character

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You can do it with a Map, it's easy.

Comment: I understand the concept in theory but could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Hashmap with a as a key and alpha symbol as value

Comment: `dictionary = [ {a, α}, {b, β}, {c, σ}...]; for (key : dictionary.getKeys()) { str = str.replaceAll(key, dictionary.get(key)) }`...

Comment: You can use HashMaps as people have already stated, but if you want to convert English letters to Greek letters, keep in mind there are only twenty-four Greek letters. However, since characters have a unicode value I suggest using an array of size 4096, and then at the index corresponding to the unicode of a character, put the character it is supposed to be replaced with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so, here are two :

- Using the `replaceAll()` method several times (https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) which basically allows you to replace each occurrence of a character in a string by something else
- By creating a Map and a function, to iterate through the String and replace each character by its corresponding one

The first is easier to implement but will be messier if you have lots of substitutions, while the second is cleaner to implement and use but requires more code to work.

Personally, I would combine these two to iterate once per map entry : in a `for` loop, use `replaceAll()` for each replaceable character.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop to do this as shown below :

- If your string is small and dictionary might contain more values - **loop through string** :

  ```
  Map<String,String> dict = new HashMap<>();
  dict.put("a", "α");
  dict.put("b", "β");
  // .... and so on
  for (char c : myString.toCharArray()) {
      String currentChar = String.valueOf(c);
      if (dict.containsKey(currentChar))
          myString = myString.replaceAll(currentChar,dict.get(currentChar));
  }
  ```
- If your string is large, while dictionary is fixed (like, contains only a-z characters) - **loop through dictionary** :

  ```
  Map<String,String> dict = new HashMap<>();
  dict.put("a", "α");
  dict.put("b", "β");
  // .... and so on
  for (String key : dict.keySet()) {
          myString = myString.replaceAll(key,dict.get(key));
  }
  ```

Comment: what an inefficient loop, why are you iterating over all the keys even if they might not be present in the original string. rather iterate over set of myString chars and replaceAll

Comment: @Shail016 This one is based on my conceptual comment and that's why it has the same approach :) There is no such method as `getKeys()` - it should be `Map::keySet`. `for` loop definition is wrong as well - it should be `for (Type key : ...)`. Also I would go for Map::forEach instead of for loop but since this is tagged android - I wont...

Answer (score 0):

I already wrote a similar function to convert accents to corresponding alphabets, It can help you

```
public static String ChangeAccentToCorrespondingChar(String string) // at the end of this function we'll only get these elements "^[a-z0-9_-]*$"
    {
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> asciiMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(){{
            put(192, 97); put(193, 97);  put(194, 97);  put(195, 97);  put(196, 97);  put(197, 97);  put(224, 97); put(225, 97); put(226, 97); put(227, 97); put(228, 97); put(229, 97); put(257, 97); put(256, 97); put(170, 97); put(131, 102); put(142, 122); put(158, 122); put(159, 121); put(221, 121); put(253, 121); put(255, 121); put(161, 105); put(204, 105); put(205, 105); put(206, 105); put(207, 105); put(236, 105); put(237, 105); put(238, 105); put(239, 105); put(299, 105); put(162, 99); put(169, 99); put(199, 99); put(231, 99); put(174, 114); put(200, 101); put(201, 101); put(202, 101); put(203, 101); put(232, 101); put(233, 101); put(234, 101); put(235, 101); put(275, 101); put(208, 100); put(209, 110); put(241, 110); put(210,111); put(211,111); put(212,111); put(213,111); put(214,111); put(216, 111); put(240, 111); put(242, 111); put(243, 111); put(244, 111); put(245, 111); put(246, 111); put(248, 111); put(333, 111); put(215, 120); put(217, 117); put(218, 117); put(219, 117); put(220, 117); put(249, 117); put(250, 117); put(251, 117); put(252, 117); put(254, 98);
        }};

        StringBuilder changedString = new StringBuilder();

        char[] charArr = string.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0;i<charArr.length;i++) {
            char character = charArr[i];
            int ascii = character;
            if (asciiMap.containsKey(ascii)) {
                ascii = asciiMap.get(ascii);
                character = (char)ascii;
            } 

        return changedString.toString();
    }
```

In your case you want to do in reverse, mean alphabets to its accent, you can simply change the ascii values in above Hashmap to retrieve your requirements. In hash map, keys are the original character's ascii and values are the new character ascii.

Comment: If i understand correctly, do i have to replace the numbers inside "put" with letters? if so which one goes first the original or the one i want it turned to?

Comment: yes these numbers are ascii values of the characters. And on left original character's ascii and on right ascii of the new character. As in my example, 192 is the ascii of "À" and 97 is ascii of "a". so "À" will be replaced with "a". If you want to change "a" to "À" (reverse order), you can keep 97 on left and 192 on right.